# disable pagination and display all results on scrolling

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I wanted to disable pagination completely and show all results for sync call,

If the `paginate` is set to `false`, I can see up to 99 on scrolling, beyond that I can only be able to search I believe. 
Is there a way, results beyond that default index be seen on scrolling down?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve that.

```
<Typeahead
    {...this.props}
    options= {objects}
    maxResults = {objects.length}
    paginate = false
/>
```

From the official document:

> paginate :  Give user the ability to display additional results if the number of results exceeds maxResults.

Detailed document : [react-bootstrap-typeahead-props](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Props.md)